Does an overlaid former roof need to remain weatherproof?
We are in the process of having a covered patio installed on our home. The beams for the patio extension are tied to the beams of my house, which required that the soffit be cut away on that side.
The frame is complete, the plywood roof has been laid down, and roofing underlayment has been added, but it has not yet been shingled.
This morning I awoke to a ton of water damage in my kitchen as it began raining heavily overnight. Water was running underneath the structure, down the shingles, and into the open walls shown in the photos above.
We've already contacted our home owners insurance company to file a claim and the contractor has agreed to cover the cost of damages.
My questions are mostly about the structure as it is currently. While I'm sure this is less likely to happen once it is shingled and flashing has been added, I'm concerned that if something was to ever happen to the shingles that water would just begin running into the wall space again. Is it normal to leave the top of the wall open and exposed like this, or should that area be sealed? If not, any recommendations on how to best fix this? Things I should be on the lookout for to make sure this is repaired correctly?



Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] so you know how this site works, then revise your title to as a single clear, specific question.

My liability insurance requires that the roof is covered and I can't imagine any underwriter leaving that out and assuming the risk that your contractor took here.
Felt underlayment is most common, and yes, if your shingles fail you can expect water damage - the manufacturers (which is where your roof gets it warranty) specifies installation methods that will preserve that warranty.
Personally, I don't use use felt underlayment. I use a product called Sharkskin Ultra SA, which is an ice and water adhesive skin. It's waterproof alone and adds a significant layer of protection.
At the end of the day, what happened was the result of your contractor not protecting the unfinished roof before the rain began. Calling your insurance company is ok, but you want this claim to be resolved by your contractor's liability insurance so you don't have a deductible coming out of your pocket.
Share your concerns with the contractor and be attentive to his confidence in the quality of his roof. If you lose trust/confidence in his performance, and you've already paid him, you can file a claim against his bond to have someone else finish the work you've already paid for.
Ideally, he follows through on owning the mistake and takes care of mitigating the water damage at no cost to you.

Thanks so much, this is very helpful.  I am going to ask about his insurance as well.  I guess I assumed that that's something I'd turn over to my home insurance company and they would work out between his insurer and mine, but maybe not.   Do you see anything else in the photos that you believe would be cause for concern?  He's coming tomorrow to survey the damage and seems to be already trying to downplay it and say he did everything he could have to prevent this.

It's very common for a new roof to overlay an old one like this with a remodel. It's not a concern any more than any of the other otherwise unprotected parts of the home are. A contractor is never going to make the former roof weathertight. One roof is enough.
In fact, the lower roof is often deliberately cut away to allow better attic ventilation from the lower compartment, create access for utility work, etc.
